# Update query for SQlite is not updating, but no error given

Tags: sqlite, web-sql

I have several queries working however the update query does not update the data and does not throw any errors either.

I'm obviously missing something, but I can't see what it is.

The select queries are working and the insert query is working its just the update query that is not working.

This is working

```
db.transaction(function (tx) {

tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO customers (firstname1,lastname1,firstname2,lastname2,email1,email2,phone1,phone2,createDate,syncDate,userId) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", [data.firstname1,data.lastname1, data.firstname2, data.lastname2, data.email1, data.email2, data.phone1, data.phone2, data.createDate, data.syncDate,data.userId], onError);
});
```

This is not working.

```
db.transaction(function (tx) { 

tx.executeSql("UPDATE customers SET firstname1 = ?, firstname2 = ?, lastname1 = ?, lastname2 = ?, phone1 = ?, phone2 = ?, email1 = ?, email2 = ? WHERE id = ?", [firstname1, lastname1, firstname2, lastname2, email1, email2, phone1, phone2, i], updateCB, onError);
});
```

Any suggestions as to where to look?

Comment: could you please provide the code of method executeSql? i see you're sending 4 parameter in the update (query,values, updateCB, onError), but in the insert you're sending 3 (query, values, on Error)...

Comment: What is the value of `i`? How do you know that it exists in the table?